# How can we change the maximum number of columns using the NiceTabular?

Tags: maximum-values

I'm using the `NiceMatrix` and `NiceTabular` environments (which are just excellent, F. Pantigny, thanks!, especially when you're using colors in cells background).

How can we change the maximum number of columns using `NiceTabular`?

I have tried to set the `maxMatrixCols` counter to say 30 (my code fails for 21 columns) but the code still fails saying:

> ! Fatal Package nicematrix Error: You try to use more columns than
> allowed by (nicematrix)                      your environment
> {NiceTabular}. The (nicematrix)                      maximal number of
> columns is 21 (plus the (nicematrix)                      potential
> exterior ones). This error is (nicematrix)                      fatal.

Many thanks for your help,
Xavier Vigan

Answer (score 5):

[image: b]

`MaxMatrixCols` is only needed with `NiceMatrix`.

Try this code.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}    
    \parindent=0pt
    \oddsidemargin=0pt  
    \small

    \begin{NiceTabular}{*{30}c}
    x&x&x&x&x&x&x&x&x&10&   x&x&x&x&x&x&x&x&x&20&   x&x&x&x&x&x&x&x&x&30        
    \end{NiceTabular}
    
    \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{30}  %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
    \[\begin{NiceMatrix}
    x&x&x&x&x&x&x&x&x&10&   x&x&x&x&x&x&x&x&x&20&   x&x&x&x&x&x&x&x&x&30        
    \end{NiceMatrix}\]      
        
\end{document}
```